# YouTube Data API only displaying 5 results at a time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I'm having this problem with the YouTube Data API where I want the page to return about 35-40+ results on the page. But instead it's only displaying 5 results per search, any help?

**CodePen:** [codepen](http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/6b6a347c7d24edee15b3491420db4ecd?editors=011)

**jQuery:**

```
var apikey = 'AIzaSyCKMpw2nmPnon_gkh4EIXnbiAmrZNw-v4M';

$(function() {
    var searchField = $('#query');

    $('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function search() {
    $('#results').html('');

    q = $('#query').val();

    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: q,
            type: 'video',
            key: apikey
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var output = getResults(item);

                $('#results').append(output);
            });
        });
}

function getResults(item) {
    var videoID = item.id.videoId;
    var title = item.snippet.title;
    var description = item.snippet.description;
    var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
    var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;

    var output = '<li>' +
        '<div class="list-left">' +
        '<img src="' + thumb + '">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="list-right">' +
        '<h3><a href="http://youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '?rel=0">' + title + '</a></h3>' +
        '<p class="cTitle">' + channelTitle + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
        '';

    return output;
}
```

As always, thanks for helping out!

Comment: Your results are probably paginated.  You will need to iterate through the pages to get all of the results you want.  From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) it does not look like you can change the `pageInfo.resultsPerPage`.

Comment: `pageInfo.resultsPerPage` is returned from the YouTube API response.  It is an integer but you **cannot** change it.  It's value is provided by YouTube.

Comment: How could I make my results not paginated?

Comment: You can't.  It's the way the API was designed.

Comment: But before, I remember being able to have the API display up to 30 results  at a time on the page, until their update came out... I am certain this is still possible, because sties like last.fm and plug.dj still do this with the new updated API.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list.  Do you see a parameter you can pass in to change the number of results per page?  The closest thing I see is the optional `maxResults` parameter which allows you to specify the max results returned total, not per page.  From the docs, what you're asking is not possible.  Are you sure those sites weren't using an older API or were running multiple YouTube queries per site page?

Comment: I'm not trying to display results per pages, I'm trying to display them all in one go, only in the div container, only about 30... I remember being able to do this with maxResults=35 about a year ago

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78952/discussion-between-jal-and-mistkaes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API docs are deceiving, `maxResults` actually sets the max results per page.

Change your GET request to add that param:

```
$.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: q,
            type: 'video',
            key: apikey,
            maxResults: 50
        },
```

50 results are now returned.